# while & foreach loop to group output of array

Tags: php, laravel, while-loop

I have an array of locations very similar to the below. What i would like to do is group by items that have the same SiteNumbers (See desired outcome), however im unsure of the best method to check the current sitenumber against the next to see if its different, currently i am checking if sitenumber = sitenumber. Any suggestions welcome

array ($locationList):

```
SiteNumber = 1001, Location = Kitchen, Position = Cupboard
SiteNumber = 1001, Location = Kitchen, Position = Fridge
SiteNumber = 1002, Location = Bedroom, Position = Bed
SiteNumber = 1002, Location = Bedroom, Position = Draws
SiteNumber = 1002, Location = Bedroom, Position = Wardrobe
```

Current code:

```
@while($locationList[0]->SiteNumber = $locationList[0]->CardNumber)

    <h3>{{ $locationList->SiteNumber }}</h3>
            <table class="tbl-striped">
                <tr>
                    <th>Location</th>
                    <th>Position</th>
                </tr>

                @foreach($locationList as $loclist)

                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ $loclist->Location }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $loclist->Position }}</td>

                    </tr>

                @endforeach


            </table>
            @endwhile
```

The desired outcome, would look something like this:

Site Number = 1001

```
Location | Position
Kitchen | Cupboard
Kitchen | Fridge
```

Site Number = 2002

```
Location | Position
Bedroom | Bed
Bedroom | Draws
Bedroom | Draws
```

Comment: You are retrieving this from a database, correct?

Comment: You should group the results by siteNumber. See my answer.

Comment: Can you use laravel features for this, or you really need to work with that array? and what `current code` is supposed to do exactly/ why it doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

You can group the results by sitenumber using SQL.

```
"SELECT * FROM sites 
 ORDER BY siteNumber"
```

You can go further by creating a new table for each sitenumber.

```
$siteNumber = 0;

if($siteNumber !== $locationList->SiteNumber) {
    $siteNumber = $locationList->SiteNumber;
    //Create new table
}
```

Of course you will have to convert the above to Laravel's templating system syntax.

Comment: I Cant see how that will help, ill end up with this:

SiteNumber = 1001, Location = Kitchen, Position = Cupboard
SiteNumber = 1002, Location = Bedroom, Position = Bed

Comment: It will group by siteNumber. So it will retrieve all 1001 first, then all 1002, and so on.

Comment: According to MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms177673.aspx

"One row is returned for each group." so i would only have 2 results based on my above example. This isnt the desired outcome.

Comment: My apologies, you don't even need a GROUP BY.